# MDT Post-Migration issue

Tags: mdt, mdtool

TLDR; we had to perform an emergency migration of our MDT files onto a new server. We have it configured, the share appears the services run but somewhere outside of the Bootstrap file and the MDT GUI exists a file sending the service to the old server, now offline. Any idea what that file might be or ways to override it without blowing up the whole deployment share?

Replaced all references to the old servers name or IP in the DeployWorkbench GUI, the Bootstrap file, any other ini files we found, and some txt files.

When trying to PxE boot from a machine it flows till authentication. When we cancel we get an error saying the system couldnt reach \ \ OLDSERVER\windows10share.

Mapping to the proper location works via cmd prompt.

Comment: PXE boot source is usually configured on the DHCP Server. Did you update this part as well?